# React Material-UI project build

Tags: reactjs, datatable, material-design, material-ui

I build a react material UI v1.4.3 project with NPM run build, but its styles are not working correctly. This is screenshots build version and none build version

Non-Build
[image: Non-Build]

Build
[image: build]

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually this is because of className collision. I had the same problem today and I managed to fix it by adding a prefix to the classNames. have a look at docs here https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator .
And also this issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8223

Comment: @HosseinDehnokhalaji can you tell me how can i fix it? i followed given link but can't understand it

Comment: Gihan I'll need to have more info. can you share some of your code?